How to rotate a gameobject on horizontal axis toward Vector3
I'm working on unity 2022.3.37 and as i said on the title, i want a gameobject to rotate (only on the vertical axis) in the direction of my vector3.
Let's said you have a gun, you shoot on a wall, the shootPoint is a vector3 and there's a compass on the ground which rotate in the direction of the shootPoint.
How could i do that ?
i've tried something like that, but it rotate on the Z axis
    // Calculate the direction from the compass to the shoot point 
    Vector3 direction = shootPoint - compass.transform.position;

    // Ignore the Y component to rotate only on the vertical axis
    direction.y = 0;

    // Check if the direction is not zero to avoid errors
    if (direction != Vector3.zero)
    {
        // Calculate the target rotation to point towards the shootPoint
        Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);

        // Apply the target rotation, keeping the rotation constrained to the Y-axis
        compass.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(90, targetRotation.eulerAngles.y, 0);
    }


Why did you set X = 90?

Is the compass supposed to rotate around its local y-axis? If you want to constrain rotation to a specific plane you can project the direction onto that plane ( ClosestPointOnPlane in unity? ) and then use lookRotation, with the result and the plane normal as the parameters.

@JonasH instead of ClosestPointOnPlane you would probably rather use Vector3.Project ;)

OP Quaternion.Euler: Returns a rotation that rotates z degrees around the z axis, x degrees around the x axis, and y degrees around the y axis; applied in that order. ... if you already rotated around X about 90° then Y doesn't point up anymore ...

@derHugo Vector3.Project is between vectors. Projection on a plane is essentially myVector - Vector3.Project(myVector, myPlane.Normal). Not sure what the best way is to do the same in Unity. If the plane passes thru origo, then ClosestPointOnPlane should probably work. Otherwise an extension method might be easiest.

@JonasH OP has a direction -> you can simply project that direction on a plane ... you don't have to care about positions ;)

though looking on it again .. OP, you already do direction.y = 0; so you basically already ensure this in in the XZ plane ... so just using targetRotation should already work anyway .. if additionally you need the X rotation add it afterwards: compass.transform.rotation = targetRotation * Quaternion.Euler(90, 0, 0);
